# How to import generated Kotlin classes from C in Kotlin/Native?

Tags: c, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin-native

I am trying a Kotlin/Native C Interop .

I successfully build Kotlin/Native project with a C header file

But don't know how to import the generated Libs. In which package they reside

For example , in App.h (see gist) , there is a function named `void printNameFromC(char* name)` . How to call this in Kotlin file ? (how to import functions packages ?)

I tried using package name given in main.cinterops.packageName, tried name in cinterops.create(**) and also manually typed function names used in header file and they not shown in suggestions

Please help me how to use the

My code:
https://gist.github.com/RageshAntony/d25232763682d2a15acbabaa1cca08bc

Screenshot of project structure
[image: prj struct]

Answer (score 1):

The result bindings should be available under the package name defined by the developer. In can either specify `package` directly inside of the `.def` file as in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-c-interop.html#create-bindings-for-a-new-library), or do the same at the `cinterops` block of the `build.gradle<.kts>` as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-dsl-reference.html#cinterops).

In this particular case, as there is no App.h in the gist, I would guess that either the `.def` file is just incorrect. Its contents are conflicting with the `cinterops` block contents, and also it contains several independent headers in one place, which should be avoided.